# PlatformIO failed to build: undefined reference to http_parser_init

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, embedded, ota, platformio

I am trying to set up over the air updates(OTA) updates using the example within the ESP-IDF framework library in PlaformIO. The ota simple_example main.c file imports a .h file called esp_http_client.h. esp_http_client imports another .h file called http_parser.h which is where the function http_parser_init is defined. I am building this project in PlaformIO in VScode so I checked the c_cpp_properties.json and both the http_parser.c and http_parser.h directories were included. I noticed that sometimes there are bugs with the c_cpp_properties file so I also included the the http_parser.h file directory in the platform.ini file.

**I also run into the error:**

undefined reference to http_parser_execute

undefined reference to http_parser_url_init

undefined reference to http_parser_parse_url

which are all functions found in the http_parser.h file

**Here is the code for the main.c file that I'm using**

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_event_loop.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_ota_ops.h"
#include "esp_http_client.h"
#include "esp_flash_partitions.h"
#include "esp_partition.h"

#include "nvs.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "main.h"
#define WIFI_SSID SSID
#define WIFI_PASS PASSWORD
#define SERVER_URL FIRMWARE_UPG_URL
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define HASH_LEN 32 /* SHA-256 digest length */

static const char *TAG = "native_ota_example";
/*an ota data write buffer ready to write to the flash*/
static char ota_write_data[BUFFSIZE + 1] = { 0 };
//  uint8_t server_cert_pem_start[] asm("_binary_ca_cert_pem_start");
//  uint8_t server_cert_pem_end[] asm("_binary_ca_cert_pem_end");


/* FreeRTOS event group to signal when we are connected & ready to make a request */
static EventGroupHandle_t wifi_event_group;

/* The event group allows multiple bits for each event,
   but we only care about one event - are we connected
   to the AP with an IP? */
const int CONNECTED_BIT = BIT0;

static esp_err_t event_handler(void *ctx, system_event_t *event)
{
    switch (event->event_id) {
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START:
        esp_wifi_connect();
        break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
        xEventGroupSetBits(wifi_event_group, CONNECTED_BIT);
        break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
        /* This is a workaround as ESP32 WiFi libs don't currently
           auto-reassociate. */
        esp_wifi_connect();
        xEventGroupClearBits(wifi_event_group, CONNECTED_BIT);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return ESP_OK;
}

static void initialise_wifi(void)
{
    tcpip_adapter_init();
    wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_event_loop_init(event_handler, NULL) );
    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_wifi_init(&cfg) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_wifi_set_storage(WIFI_STORAGE_RAM) );
    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .sta = {
            .ssid = SSID,
            .password = PASSWORD,
        },
    };
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Setting WiFi configuration SSID %s...", wifi_config.sta.ssid);
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_config) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK( esp_wifi_start() );
}

static void http_cleanup(esp_http_client_handle_t client)
{
    esp_http_client_close(client);
    esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
}

static void __attribute__((noreturn)) task_fatal_error()
{
    ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Exiting task due to fatal error...");
    (void)vTaskDelete(NULL);

    while (1) {
        ;
    }
}

void print_sha256 (const uint8_t *image_hash, const char *label)
{
    char hash_print[HASH_LEN * 2 + 1];
    hash_print[HASH_LEN * 2] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_LEN; ++i) {
        sprintf(&hash_print[i * 2], "%02x", image_hash[i]);
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "%s: %s", label, hash_print);
}

static void ota_example_task(void *pvParameter)
{

    esp_err_t err;
    /* update handle : set by esp_ota_begin(), must be freed via esp_ota_end() */
    esp_ota_handle_t update_handle = 0 ;
    const esp_partition_t *update_partition = NULL;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Starting OTA example...");

    const esp_partition_t *configured = esp_ota_get_boot_partition();
    const esp_partition_t *running = esp_ota_get_running_partition();

    if (configured != running) {
        ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Configured OTA boot partition at offset 0x%08x, but running from offset 0x%08x",
                 configured->address, running->address);
        ESP_LOGW(TAG, "(This can happen if either the OTA boot data or preferred boot image become corrupted somehow.)");
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Running partition type %d subtype %d (offset 0x%08x)",
             running->type, running->subtype, running->address);

    /* Wait for the callback to set the CONNECTED_BIT in the
       event group.
    */
    xEventGroupWaitBits(wifi_event_group, CONNECTED_BIT,
                        false, true, portMAX_DELAY);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connect to Wifi ! Start to Connect to Server....");

    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = SERVER_URL,
        // .cert_pem = (char *)server_cert_pem_start,
    };
    esp_http_client_handle_t client = esp_http_client_init(&config);
    if (client == NULL) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialise HTTP connection");
        task_fatal_error();
    }
    err = esp_http_client_open(client, 0);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to open HTTP connection: 1");
        esp_http_client_cleanup(client);
        task_fatal_error();
    }
    esp_http_client_fetch_headers(client);

    update_partition = esp_ota_get_next_update_partition(NULL);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Writing to partition subtype %d at offset 0x%x",
             update_partition->subtype, update_partition->address);
    assert(update_partition != NULL);

    err = esp_ota_begin(update_partition, OTA_SIZE_UNKNOWN, &update_handle);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "esp_ota_begin failed 3");
        http_cleanup(client);
        task_fatal_error();
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "esp_ota_begin succeeded");

    int binary_file_length = 0;
    /*deal with all receive packet*/
    while (1) {
        int data_read = esp_http_client_read(client, ota_write_data, BUFFSIZE);
        if (data_read < 0) {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Error: SSL data read error");
            http_cleanup(client);
            task_fatal_error();
        } else if (data_read > 0) {
            err = esp_ota_write( update_handle, (const void *)ota_write_data, data_read);
            if (err != ESP_OK) {
                http_cleanup(client);
                task_fatal_error();
            }
            binary_file_length += data_read;
            ESP_LOGD(TAG, "Written image length %d", binary_file_length);
        } else if (data_read == 0) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connection closed,all data received");
            break;
        }
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Total Write binary data length : %d", binary_file_length);

    if (esp_ota_end(update_handle) != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "esp_ota_end failed!");
        http_cleanup(client);
        task_fatal_error();
    }

    if (esp_ota_get_running_partition() == update_partition) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "The current running firmware is same as the firmware just downloaded");
        int i = 0;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "When a new firmware is available on the server, press the reset button to download it");
        while(1) {
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Waiting for a new firmware ... %d", ++i);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
    }

    err = esp_ota_set_boot_partition(update_partition);
    if (err != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "esp_ota_set_boot_partition failed 2!");
        http_cleanup(client);
        task_fatal_error();
    }
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Prepare to restart system!");
    esp_restart();
    return ;
}


void app_main()
{

    // Initialize NVS.
    nvs_flash_init();
        // OTA app partition table has a smaller NVS partition size than the non-OTA
        // partition table. This size mismatch may cause NVS initialization to fail.
        // If this happens, we erase NVS partition and initialize NVS again.
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
        nvs_flash_init();


    initialise_wifi();
    xTaskCreate(&ota_example_task, "ota_example_task", 8192, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

The http_parser.h: [file](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components/nghttp/port/include)

The esp_http_client: [file](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components/esp_http_client/include)

I don't understand where I'm supposed to define these functions when they are defined in the esp_parser.h file or what I'm supposed to do to not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by compiling the program without PlatformIO.

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/

Here are the guide to install the toolchain.

Regards

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).